# Phaser3 Tiled Map Editor İmage Layer(can't use image layer for background)

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework, tiled, tmxtiledmap

I create an image layer in the tiled map editor, I place it on the map (I will use it as background) I get exported as json, I cannot use it in phaser3, but how to use it.
I can use other layers, I can see them, but I can't see the image layer and technically it shouldn't be where I placed it in tiled, there is no problem in preload.

Edit ;

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the images names from the image layers with the function `getImageLayerNames` [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap.html), but I'm not 100% sure how it works since I never tried it.

**Update**:
I tried it now you would only need to get the image name from the property `images` from the `map` object.

**Mini Code:**

```js
let map = this.add.tilemap('map');
// if you know the imagelayer name, if not use the "getImageLayerNames" function to find the naes
let bgName = 'BG';

let imageOfImageLayer = map.images.find(layer => layer.name == bgName );
// maybe check if it was found or not
```

You would need to preload the first *(or load it later in a more complicated way)*. if you use the filename as key it makes it easy.

**for example:**

```js
preload(){
    this.load.image('bg.png', 'bg.png')
    // ...
}
```

And in the `create` function set them as any other image, with `this.add.image(...)`, and the values from the layer.

**Update 2 / Solution:**

You would have to add the image, best in the `create` function. something like this:

```js
const BG_KEY = "background";

class MyScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    ...
    preload(){
        this.load.image(BG_KEY , 'bg.png')
        // ...
    }

    create(){
        this.map = this.add.tilemap('map');
        // ...
        let imageOfImageLayer = this.map.images.find(
            (layer) => layer.name == BG_KEY 
        );

        this.add.image(imageOfImageLayer.x, imageOfImageLayer.y, imageOfImageLayer.name)
            // like this you can set the origin of the coordinates, by default it is in the middle
            .setOrigin(0,0);
        // ...
    }
```

> **btw.:** If you want to load images manually without using the `preload` function (because you want to use the filename provided in the tiled file), you can checkout this [official phaser example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cloader%5Cloader%20events%5Cstart%20loader%20manually.js), which shows how to manually load images, after `preload`.
> It's alot more work so I would not recomend it, if it is not 100% necessary.

Comment: p.s.: you can also access the other properties if needed. like `visible`, `alpha` or your own customs properties.

Comment: I was add an edit. 
This is the background I made in my tiled map editor, it is 0,0 this way, but in the game scene it does not appear as it appears here, it is formed higher and half of it appears.

Comment: @yunusemreagdin yes, you would have to set, `setOrigin` to `0`, to position the image correctly, I updated my answer to show this.

Comment: here is the [link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.54.0/Phaser.GameObjects.Image#setorigin), to the `setOrigin` for the image gameobject.